# Algorithm paused in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have 3 buttons, play, pause and next. When i click the play button, a function is called(long time execution). I want to click the "pause" button so the code will stop. The next time i want to click "Play", i want it to continue from where it stopped. 
Also i want the "next" button do execute the next line of code and then pause.
 
At first i tried to stop a function with a button, but i'm stuck

```
var nrs,nrst:int;
nrs=1;
nrst=0;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
butt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, cont);
qwe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, conts);

function chs():Boolean
{
    if (nrs==1) return true; else return false;
}

function cont(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    while (chs()==true)
    {
        nrst++;
        nrst=nrst%1234;
        str.text=nrst.toString();
    }
}
function conts (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nrs=0;
}
```

Comment: And yes, if you want to execute code line by line, use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is, your function should work in start-stop mode in itself in order for you to srop process execution. This is because Flash event engine requires the event listener to actually end before another event can be launched. I have solved this with the following approach: Make an enterframe listener, make ONE cycle of your function to execute within it (**make sure no local vars are used that should be available between cycles!**) and exit the listener. Make a set of variables (best to use one, but it's not performance friendly) that this cycle will update each time it's run. Either control cycle execution via global var/function like you have tried, or add/remove listener itself. The global flag is better, as you can accidentally add two listeners and possibly screw up the process. In your simple case the structure will look like this:

```
butt.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, conts2);
qwe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, conts);
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,cont);

function chs():Boolean
{
    if (nrs==1) return true; else return false;
}

function cont(event:Event):void
{
    if (chs()) // IF, not WHILE, so that events could still be parsed
    {
        nrst++;
        nrst=nrst%1234;
        str.text=nrst.toString();
    }
}
function conts (event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nrs=0;
}
function conts2(e:MouseEvent):void {
    nrs=1;
}
```